# How to create a horizontal calendar with nested lists?

Tags: css, html-lists, nested-lists

I want to create a date chooser like this:

```
| 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 .. 29 30 31 | 1 2 3 4 ..
| January                       | February
```

I think the best structure for this would be:

```html
 <div class="outer">
   <ol>
     <li class="month">
     January
       <ol>
         <li class="day">1</li>
         <li class="day">2</li>
         <li class="day">3</li>
         ...
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li class="month">
        February
        <ol>
          <li class="day">1</li>
          <li class="day">2</li>
          <li class="day">3</li>
          ...
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
 </div>
```

Now I would like the outer divs (`.month`) to expand to the inner divs (`.day`), which are all of the same width. And then have that in a big horizontal div (`.outer`) so I can scroll the innards.
I already got this to work with only one month, but when I add more months to it, it doesn't work anymore.

I obviously cannot set a fixed with for the months because they dont have the same amount of days.

I set up [a Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/g6u52vhn/1/)  with some css, but it doesn't work and I dont know how to go about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These kind of questions are just fun to answer step-by-step.

[The basics of the solution is to display all list items as inline-block:](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/b1tdctb4/6/)

```css
.calendar > ol > li {
    display: inline-block;
}
.calendar > ol > li > ol {
    padding: 0;
}
.calendar > ol > li > ol > li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

[Give the dates a fixed size, put all months on a single line, and let the container scroll:](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/b1tdctb4/9/)

```css
.calendar {
    overflow-x: auto;
}
.calendar > ol {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.calendar > ol > li {
    display: inline-block;
}
.calendar > ol > li > ol {
    padding: 0;
}
.calendar > ol > li > ol > li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
}
```

[And finally, shuffle the months' and the dates' positions](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/b1tdctb4/10/), resulting in this snippit:

```css
.calendar {
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}
.calendar > ol {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin-bottom: -1em;
}
.calendar > ol > li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 1em;
}
.calendar > ol > li > ol {
    padding: 0;
}
.calendar > ol > li > ol > li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 30px;
    position: relative;
    top: -2.2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="calendar">
    <ol>
        <li>January
            <ol>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
                <li>4</li>
                <li>5</li>
                <li>6</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li>February
            <ol>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
                <li>4</li>
                <li>5</li>
                <li>6</li>
                <li>7</li>
                <li>8</li>
                <li>9</li>
                <li>10</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li>March
            <ol>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
                <li>4</li>
                <li>5</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li>April
            <ol>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
                <li>4</li>
                <li>5</li>
                <li>6</li>
            </ol>
        </li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

Note that this is a strict CSS2 solution compatible with even the oldest browser, does not use absolute positioning so it has no consequence for the content around it, requires just a single style class, is compatible with [every font size](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/b1tdctb4/11/), and has no impact on the markup at all.

Comment: Thank you. Very clean, easy to implement.

Answer (score 1):

I have completely rewritten your CSS, because it is hard to determine what look you want to go for. I have chosen to use the latest [CSS3 flexbox specification](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) — simply because it allows me to reposition the month relative to the dates without using `position`, which will be extremely messy. You might want to use vendor prefixes to ensure maximal cross-browser support for CSS3 flexbox.

See proof-of-concept fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/g6u52vhn/4/. The only changes I made to your markup is to wrap the months in `<span>` tags ;)

I have taken the liberty to add borders so you can clearly distinguish the different elements.

```
.dates {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 5%;
    width: 90%;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: auto;
}

/* General list styles */
.dates ol {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.dates li {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-shrink: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

/* Specific styles */
.dates > ol > li {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.dates .month span {
    border: 1px solid #999;
    display: block;
    order: 2;
    width: 100%;
}
.dates .month ol {
    order: 1;
}
.dates .month ol li {
    border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

However, if you need to support older browsers, you might want to fallback to the good old `<table>` element, which I feel would be sufficient and valid.

Comment: Thank you Terry. Very interesting with the flex. I will sure try that - for the moment I go with Veens solution since it is nearer at my current codebase.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g6u52vhn/5/) Link.
Not much change in your CSS part but one slight change in your HTML part, I have given class to the `dates > OL` because the `dates > OL > LI > OL` is by default taking CSS from the parent OL.
Also I have put the LI text which contains the months name in a `span`.

**HTML Part: Updated**

```
....<div class="dates">
    <ol class="datesOL">
        <li class="month">....
```

**CSS Part: Updated**

```
.dates {
    height: 60px;
}

.datesOL {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px;
    overflow: scroll;
}

.dates ol li {
    overflow: auto;
}

.dates ol li ol {
    display: block;
    padding: 0;
    height: 12px; // removed
    top: -80px; // removed
}

.dates ol li ol li {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20px;
}
```

Comment: You should try to avoid absolute positioning, because it pulls the calendar out of the content. Also, this solution is not compatible with different font sizes, see [this update of your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NGLN/g6u52vhn/11/).

Comment: @NGLN But you don't know the other person's(@Johanness) requirement or may be the project requirement. So I have corrected this with required/minimum changes.

Comment: I understand. I always try to think beyond the actual question. It might be a tick. ;-)